Atomization and excitation in AES
AES (atomic emission spectroscopy) is often mentioned as both quantitative and qualitative analyzing method. From this site Atomic Emission Spectroscopy the sources such as flame and ICP are used. However, I wonder if the graphite furnace could be used in this case? Since the site does not mention about graphite furnace?
I was thinking that graphite furnace could not provide sufficient energy to excite atom compared with flame and ICP. Is it right?

This is a good question as to why graphite furnace in atomic absorption cannot be used for atomic emission spectroscopy. Keep in mind that the temperature of the graphite furnace is quite high, higher than the acetylene-air flame. Since temperature controls the excited state population, a lot of people should be emission spectroscopy in graphite furnaces. They did but not many elements work. It was not a successful idea.
Well, the key reason is for not using graphite furnace is that the sample stays in path for a very short time. The gas phase atoms are not trapped like a flame but they can diffuse out at both ends of the tube. Also, the temperature of the furnace is not constant. It is temperature programmed. Therefore, flames and plasma are more suitable for atomic emission measurements where the temperature is constant.
In older times, DC spark emission spectroscopy was common but the amount of sample was way higher than what a graphite furnace deals with.

A difference between 1) flames and ICP atom reservoirs and 2) graphite furnace atom reservoirs is that the former have a continuous replenishment of analyte whereas the graphite furnace is “one shot”: the sample is loaded on the Lvov platform in the furnace, then the furnace is heated to dry, ash and atomize the sample. The flow of sheathing inert gas then flushes the analyte away to the exhaust.

It is not clear from the answer that it speaks selectively against graphite AES and not against graphite AAS as well

Graphite furnaces can indeed be used for the purposes of atomizing a sample for atomic absorption spectroscopy, see the Wikipedia page on the subject.
However, and what I would like to clarify, is that there is something missing from the graphite furnace that your Libretexts link mentions briefly: for emission spectroscopy to work, it must:

atomize the sample, that is, break it down into its constituent atoms.
excite the atoms, so that enough atoms may relax by emission of light that you measure.

Flames and plasmas do this all in one -- the heat generated by either atomizes the sample, and these atoms are then thermally excited. The graphite furnace does not necessarily thermally excite the atomized sample enough to obtain emission, meaning it does not do step 2, it only achieves atomization.
So, if you were to use a graphite furnace, in general, they work only to vaporize and atomize the sample, and an additional excitation source would be needed to obtain a sufficient amount of emitted light.
To answer your final question, I would actually disagree with you. Graphite furnaces can provide much more thermal energy (3000 C) than an acetylene flame (2200 C), for example. The difference lies in the flame's ability to excite the atomized sample.
I hope this helps.

This statement is not totally correct, "The graphite furnace does not necessarily thermally excite the atomized sample enough to obtain emission, meaning it does not do step 2, it only achieves atomization." The main issue is residence time. If we were to trap the gas phase atoms in the furnace, we would see their emission if their resonance lines were relatively low energy lines.
